# AWS DAX with dynogels

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax, dynogels

I trying to use DAX with dynogels but it just stuck there until my lambda timeout when I do the `scan()`.

Here how I initialize the DAX.

```
import AmazonDaxClient from 'amazon-dax-client';
const dax = new AmazonDaxClient({endpoints: [env.Endpoint], region: 'us-west-2'});
const docClient = new dynogels.AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({service: dax});
dynogels.documentClient(docClient)
```

When I do `Model.scan()` it just processing until timeout without any error.

Is it the correct way to init DAX for dynogels ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` in your Lambda function so that Lambda will properly shut down when using DAX.